# ParametricNDSolve and NDSolve inside Manipulate environment

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I have a system of three coupled differential equations that can be pretty readily solved by NDSolve:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (x[t]*1.99*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(1.99*x[t] +  2.13*y[t] + 2.34*z[t]) - x[t], 
y'[t] == (y[t]*2.13*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(1.99*x[t] +2.13*y[t] + 2.34*z[t]) - y[t], 
z'[t] == (z[t]*2.34*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(1.99*x[t] + 2.13*y[t] + 2.34*z[t]) - z[t], x[0] == 1900, y[0] == 90 , 
z[0] == 10}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

and this works fine. But I'd like to change the constant 1.99 to a variable "a" and see how this affects the solution. In principle, I should be able to do this in the manipulate environment, but I'm having issues getting it to work. Initially, I tried a simple approach:

```
 Manipulate[Plot[z[t] /. NDSolve[{x'[
   t] == (x[t]*a*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(a*x[t] + 2.13*y[t] + 
      2.34*z[t]) - x[t], 
 y'[t] == (y[t]*2.13*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(a*x[t] + 2.13*y[t] + 
      2.34*z[t]) - y[t], 
 z'[t] == (z[t]*2.34*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(a*x[t] + 2.13*y[t] + 
      2.34*z[t]) - z[t], x[0] == 1900, y[0] == 90 , 
 z[0] == 10}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10}], {t, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5}]
```

But this yields an error of the form that a constant value cannot be used as a variable. I tried using ParametricNDSolve and got the same error. I've seen a few threads on using NDSolve with manipulate but none of them is directly helping me here. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong, or how I might be able to rewrite this? And should NDSolve or Parametric NDSolve be employed?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to code intermediate steps as separate functions, e.g.

```
solve[a_?NumericQ] := 
 z /. First@
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == (x[t]*a*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(a*x[t] + 2.13*y[t] + 2.34*z[t]) - x[t], 
 y'[t] == (y[t]*2.13*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(a*x[t] + 2.13*y[t] + 
      2.34*z[t]) - y[t], 
 z'[t] == (z[t]*2.34*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(a*x[t] + 2.13*y[t] + 
      2.34*z[t]) - z[t], x[0] == 1900, y[0] == 90, 
 z[0] == 10}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

then simply

```
Manipulate[
 With[{z = solve[a]},
  LogPlot[z[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 10^{-3, 3}]
], {a, 0, 5}]
```

gives you a desired answer.

Comment: That's a very cool approach, thanks for that! I found a workaround (posted below) but I think I'll try wrap my head around your idea for future!

Answer (score 2):

I found a relatively easy solution to my problem, if anyone is interested! The error messages disappear when you use wrap the z[t]/.NDSolve[....] section with Evaluate, by

```
Manipulate[ Plot[Evaluate[ z[t] /. NDSolve[{x'[
    t] == (x[t]*a*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(a*x[t] + 2.13*y[t] + 
       2.34*z[t]) - x[t], 
  y'[t] == (y[t]*2.13*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(a*x[t] + 2.13*y[t] + 
       2.34*z[t]) - y[t], 
  z'[t] == (z[t]*2.34*(x[t] + y[t] + z[t]))/(a*x[t] + 2.13*y[t] + 
       2.34*z[t]) - z[t], x[0] == 1900, y[0] == 90, 
  z[0] == 10}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10}]], {t, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5}]
```

and this works perfectly. Hope that helps someone else!